# URL that opens in Lightning or Classic depending on user setting

Tags: urlhacking

I have an excel table that I share with my sales reps. Each row in the file has has a link that open a specific opportunity record. The issue I'm facing is that the link opens in Lightning but some of my reps still use Classic. Is there any way to create a link that will open an opportunity record in Classic or Lightning depending on which version the user is currently using?

Comment: That is not possible.  But why not use a report in Salesforce instead of an Excel file?

Answer (score 2):

You can't provide a URL that will do this conditionally for you. If you give a user a Lightning URL and they don't have lightning access, they'll just see an *error*. The following [help doc about the gotchas](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lex_switching_considerations.htm&type=5) covers this

| Lightning Experience User Permission | User's Default Interface | Where Links Open |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | Lightning Experience | Links to unsupported pages are directed to Salesforce Classic, which opens in a new tab. This temporary redirection doesn’t change the user’s default interface to Salesforce Classic. The next time the user selects a link that is supported in the new interface, the Salesforce Classic tab is reloaded to open the link in Lightning Experience. |
| Yes | Salesforce Classic | Links usually open in Salesforce Classic.If a link was generated in Lightning Experience, the link opens in Lightning Experience. The user’s default interface doesn’t change to Lightning Experience. |
| No | Salesforce Classic | Links open in Salesforce Classic only. If a link was generated in Lightning Experience, the link doesn’t open, because the user can’t access Lightning Experience. |

I'm going to assume those Classic users just don't have access to Lightning (versus them just not switching to use LEX as default). As highlighted above, if they don't have access to LEX then they'll have to have a Classic URL which will be different than LEX

Since it's already an excel sheet - then you might as well just as have two columns/links/hyperlinks

- one for classic
- one for lightning

Those who still use classic will click on their relevant link. Once that is no longer true, just delete the column

For the URLs

- Classic `mydomain.my.salesforce.com/OppId`
- Lightning `mydomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/OppId`